# Using Match and Index functions in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I am trying to use VBA to look up a value in a photo-metric report (numeric angle values for column and row labels with numeric values in the array). I am trying to use the match function and the index function. However, Code that works in the worksheet automatically returns a #VALUE error when in my UDF.

```
    Dim H_10 As Double
    Dim V_5 As Double
    Dim hangle As Double
    Dim vangle As Double


    H_10 = WorksheetFunction.MRound(h, 10)
    V_5 = WorksheetFunction.MRound(v, 5)
            ' rounds off angle values to match row and collumn headers
    hangle = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(H_10, "B42:T42", 0)
    vangle = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(V_5, "A43:A79", 0)
            'looks up the row/column index
   cd = Application.Index("B43:T79", hangle, vangle, 0)
            ' uses row and column index to find value in array
```

I originally had the  the match functions within the index function but pulled them out to troubleshoot.

I have tried simply placing numbers I know to be there in the index function but when ever it or match is active I get #VALUE errors across the board.

Comment: You can more easily debug your function by calling it from another Sub, instead of from the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

`WorksheetFunctions` require the use of range objects not range strings.  Change the range strings to: `Range("RangeString")`